# Problems with DSolve[] funtion

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a differential equation but  Mathematica doesn't do it. Can you Help me please? Why doesn't Mathematica do it? 
this is my code

```
DSolve[{M'[t] == -(a + I b) M[t] - I o Exp[-I b t] Z[t]
  , P'[t] == -(a - I b) M[t] + I o Exp[I b t] Z[t],
  Z'[t] == -2 a Z[t] + 2 I o Exp[-I b t] P[t] - 
    2 I O Exp[I b t] M[t]}, {M[t], P[t], Z[t]}, t]
```

but  Mathematica doesn't do it

Im following this book and the equation and its solution 
[image]

Comment: `O` is a built-in symbol. Don't use it.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that this set of differential equations admits an analytic solution? Otherwise, specify numerical parameters and use `NDSolve`.

Comment: I'm following  a book and in this the system is solved

Comment: I change the symbol O by o  but nothing

Comment: Which book is the system solved in?

Comment: @ojlm, the book is An Open Systems Approach to Quantum Optics, the eqns are in chapters 3, page 40-41. It does not give a derivation of the answer, it just states the final solution.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know why mathematica won't solve the eqn. system as it is, mathematica does solve it if you make a change of variables. You can change the eqns into a first order linear systems of ODE using `M(t)=Exp[-I b t] m(t)` and `P(t)=Exp[I b t] p(t)`

```
DSolve[{m'[t] - I b m[t] == -(a + I b) m[t] - I o Z[t], 
p'[t] + I b p[t] == -(a - I b) p[t] + I o Z[t], 
Z'[t] == -2 a Z[t] + 2 I o p[t] - 2 I o m[t]}, {m[t], p[t], Z[t]}, t]
```

works. Also I think your second eqn has a mistake, `M(t)` should be `P(t)`.